# How do I join a table to this result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as T1 and table as T2 like the following:

T1

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id | price  | email
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | $1000  | jacky@domain.com
2  | $2000  | angle@domain.com
3  | $3000  | kevin@domain.com
-------------------------------------------------------
```

T2

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id | master | country | key   | value
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1      | US      | price | $399 
2  | 1      | US      | email | jacky/domain.us 
3  | 1      | ES      | price | $550 
4  | 1      | ES      | email | jacky@domain.es 
5  | 1      | JP      | price | $820 
6  | 1      | JP      | email | jacky@domain.jp 
7  | 2      | US      | price | $360 
8  | 2      | US      | email | angle@domain.us 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

How to get this result:

T3

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | price  | price_US  | price_ES  | price_JP  | email            | email_US        | email_ES        | email_JP
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | $1000  | $399      | $550      | $820      | jacky@domain.com | jacky@domain.us | jacky@domain.es | jacky@domain.jp
1  | $2000  | $360      | NULL      | NULL      | angle@domain.com | angle@domain.us | NULL            | NULL
1  | $3000  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL             | NULL            | NULL            | NULL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or can I get this result in PHP?

T4

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id | price  | email             | more_info
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | $1000  | jacky@domain.com  | [array (rows...)]
2  | $2000  | angle@domain.com  | [array (rows...)]
3  | $3000  | kevin@domain.com  | [array (rows...)]
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea?

## EDIT 1

Or can I get the result as the following?

T5 (US of country's result)

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id | price  | email
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | $399   | jacky@domain.us
2  | $360   | angle@domain.us
3  | $3000  | kevin@domain.com
-------------------------------------------------------
```

T6 (JP of country's result)

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id | price   | email
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | $820    | jacky@domain.jp
2  | $2000   | angle@domain.com
3  | $3000   | kevin@domain.com
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: any reason not to have t2 like that: id | master | country | price   | email

Comment: Because I have many like T1 tables must to relevant with T2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of data transformation is a *pivot*. MySQL does not have a pivot function, but you can replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.price,
  max(case when t2.country = 'US' and `key` = 'price' then t2.value end) Price_US,
  max(case when t2.country = 'ES' and `key` = 'price' then t2.value end) Price_ES,
  max(case when t2.country = 'JP' and `key` = 'price' then t2.value end) Price_JP,
  t1.email,
  max(case when t2.country = 'US' and `key` = 'email' then t2.value end) Email_US,
  max(case when t2.country = 'ES' and `key` = 'email' then t2.value end) Email_ES,
  max(case when t2.country = 'JP' and `key` = 'email' then t2.value end) Email_JP
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.master
group by t1.id, t1.price, t1.email
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/457b0/3)

Edit #1, if you just want to use joins instead of the aggregate functions, then your query will be similar to this:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.price,
  P_US.value Price_US,
  P_ES.value Price_ES,
  P_JP.value Price_JP,
  t1.email,
  E_US.value Email_US,
  E_ES.value Email_ES,
  E_JP.value Email_JP
from table1 t1
left join table2 P_US
  on t1.id = P_US.master
  and P_US.country = 'US'
  and P_US.`key` = 'price'
left join table2 P_ES
  on t1.id = P_ES.master
  and P_ES.country = 'ES'
  and P_ES.`key` = 'price'
left join table2 P_JP
  on t1.id = P_JP.master
  and P_JP.country = 'JP'
  and P_JP.`key` = 'price'
left join table2 E_US
  on t1.id = E_US.master
  and E_US.country = 'US'
  and E_US.`key` = 'email'
left join table2 E_ES
  on t1.id = E_ES.master
  and E_ES.country = 'ES'
  and E_ES.`key` = 'email'
left join table2 E_JP
  on t1.id = E_JP.master
  and E_JP.country = 'JP'
  and E_JP.`key` = 'email'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/457b0/15)

Result:

```
| ID | PRICE | PRICE_US | PRICE_ES | PRICE_JP |            EMAIL |        EMAIL_US |        EMAIL_ES |        EMAIL_JP |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |  1000 |      399 |      550 |      820 | jacky@domain.com | jacky/domain.us | jacky@domain.es | jacky@domain.jp |
|  2 |  2000 |      360 |   (null) |   (null) | angle@domain.com | angle@domain.us |          (null) |          (null) |
|  3 |  3000 |   (null) |   (null) |   (null) |     kevin@domain |          (null) |          (null) |          (null) |
```

Edit #2: To get the result similar to `T5` and `T6`, then you will use the following.  For `T6` replace the `US` with `JP`:

```
select t1.id,
  max(case when `key` = 'price' then value end) price,
  max(case when `key` = 'email' then value end) email
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.master
where t2.country = 'US'
group by t1.id
union all
select t1.id,
  t1.price,
  t1.email
from table1 t1
where not exists (select t.id
                  from table1 t
                  left join table2 t2
                    on t.id = t2.master
                  where t2.country = 'US'
                     and t1.id = t.id);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/457b0/41)

Comment: If I don't know T1 table's fields name, is possible gets T3 table?

Comment: @joe I don't understand, what table don't you know the values of?

Comment: Or u can simply join to the table twice (or just modify it as I suggested in the comment above, and do a very simple join)

Comment: Because I will be a lot like the T1 table, I wish there is a very simply unified query way. can I?

Comment: thanks for your answer, If I want T5 or T6 results how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think try to give relation between tables and then try again.

Comment: Are you have any idea for that relation between tables?